# Edge label position and rotation change in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
   roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black!60, fill=blue!5, thick, , minimum size=3.5mm},
   EdgeStyle/.style={draw=black, thick,font=\fontsize{8}{0}\selectfont}]

   \node[roundnode,label={[label distance=.5mm]90:\rotatebox{0}{\scriptsize ND}}]   (n1)    at  (0.84,1.00)         {\scriptsize 1};
   \node[roundnode,label={[label distance=.5mm]45:\rotatebox{5}{\scriptsize G}}]    (g2)    at  (2.04,1.26)         {\scriptsize 2};

   \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
   \draw [EdgeStyle,-,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\scriptsize\myshift|Long long text}}}] (n1) to [bend left=10]  (g2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can rotate, change the position of `node label` using `\rotatebox`and `lable={[]X:}` respectively. However, don't know that how to get those attribute for `edge label` in the above-mentioned format.

Comment: Are the large dimensions in `(84,100) ` and `(204,126)` by chance unintended? Consider replacing them by `(0.84,1.00) ` and `(2.04,1.26)` or append `pt` to get something that can be compiled.

Comment: (0.84,1.00) and (2.04,1.26) are ok for me.

Comment: Then please go ahead and edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

i must confess that i'm lost in your code. also question is not clear to me. i suspect, that you like to rotate edge and node labels. if this is a case, than try:

**edit:**
now, after all comments, it is (slightly :-) ) more clear what is going about label distances, and bending lines and text. considering all your comments the solution seems that can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,  
                fit,               % added
                positioning,       % not used
                quotes}            % added

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\scriptsize,
every label/.append style = {label distance=0pt, node distance=1pt},
  roundnode/.style = {circle, draw=black!60, fill=blue!5, thick,
                      minimum size=3.5mm},
every edge quotes/.append style = {sloped},
      IXS/.style={inner xsep=#1},
      IYS/.style={inner ysep=#1},
tap/.style args = {#1/#2}{decoration={raise=#1,
                                      text along path,
                                      text align={align=center},
                                      text={#2}
                                      },
              postaction={decorate},
              font=\scriptsize
              },
                   ]
\node[roundnode,label=90:ND] (n1)    {1};
\node[roundnode,label={[rotate=90]45:G}] (g2) at (120pt,26pt) {2};
% bounding box, if needed
\useasboundingbox%
    node (BB) [%draw,       % use when you defining its size
      IYS=24pt, yshift=8pt, % set by trail and error method
      fit=(n1) (g2)] {};
% edge label    
\draw (n1) edge ["1894" IXS=12mm, rotate=90]  (g2);
% bending text
\path [draw=red, tap={-12pt/text along path}]
                (n1)    to [bend right] (g2);
% bounding box, if needed
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**note:** bending as well `inner sep` introduce to image invisible points (labels borders, bending coordinates) which increase white space around visible part of image. it can be cut-of with defining own `bounding box` (as is done in above mwe). it has to be insert in code before use of edge quotes and bending edges.

for details, more information please read *tikz & pgf manual*, v3.0.1a, i.e.:

- for quotes section: *17.12.2 Nodes on Edges: Quotes Syntax*, page 247.
- for decoration of paths with text: *24.2 Decorating a Subpath Using the Decorate Path Command*, page 352
- it is worth to read complete third part of manual: *tikz is kein zeichen program*, page 118 -- 362.

Comment: I was also lost, +1....

Comment: How to change the position precisely? Ex: 1cm distance from center of the line (as in case of node label). Also, I need the bending part

Comment: please edit your question, use my image and show on it, what you like to obtain. for bending just add for example `bending left` to `edge options, for distance i need to read manual (what you can do too :-).

Comment: @Mr.EU, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: [Check here](https://imgur.com/8RS68qA). The _bent text_ will be along the line also rotation of _bent text_ which is shown with rotation in upper figure.

Comment: @Mr.EU, see edited answer.

Comment: @Zarko thanks for your effort. In your answer, `\draw` is working fine for both positive `IXS` and `IYS`. However, it is not working for negative values (after the label reaches its centre position, it is not shifting further). In `\path`we are getting shifting (in my example too), but not rotation and non-centred label position.

Comment: @Mr.EU, IXS (acronym for inner xshift) can be begative, but will not move label on opposite site of edge. for this you need to add option `swap`. btw, is answer helpful to you?

Comment: I think, it is getting more and more complicated. In this case better to use somthing like `\node[label={[label distance=.5mm]90:\rotatebox{45}{\scriptsize myComplexLabelPosition}}]   (n1)    at  (1.84,2.00)         {};` for proper position and `\draw [decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={SOME LONG TEXT}}] (0,1.5) to [bend right=30] (3,5);` for bent text

Comment: Where to use `swap`?